# How to create a newcommand with acronym?

Tags: acronyms

I'd like to know how can I make `\acronym` such like this example:

1. *Picture Superiority Effect* (ang.; PSE) means ...
2. acronym PSE (from ang. *Picture Superiority Effect*) means...

I have to create a `\newcommand \ang{}` and `\angs{}`

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you explain what you want `\ang` etc. to do and provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing which documentclass etc. you are using.

Comment: The `glossaries` package manages acronyms. However, I don't know if there might be simpler options if you are only interested in acronyms.